# In angular 10 how to reduce mat form field appearance outline border size

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

In angular 10, using @angular/material, how can I reduce the `mat-form-field` appearance of the outline border on hover state.

I am able to modify the default border size using this code:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: black;
}
```

On hover a thick black color is showing like this

[image]

I need to show it like this on hover

[image]

Comment: what happens when you inspect CSS ? Do you see what is the selector giving this style ?

Comment: I did inspect checking for css.did may css code.But on hover apperance thick border line size is not able to reduce

Comment: in the code you wrote, there is no `:hover`, so indeed it does not affect the hover state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the input element in the browser, you'll notice that the hover state affects 3 inner elements inside `.mat-form-field-outline`. Therefore, to force all those elements to get a black border with a 1px width even on hover state, you could do this:

```css
.mat-form-field ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.mat-form-field ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-gap,
.mat-form-field ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px !important;
}
```

> ⚡ Here is a working example: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-66985351](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-66985351?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)